# Using "if" as an expression

Tags: scala

I wonder, why can't I compile this one:

```
class MyClass{
  override def toString = "123:" + if (true) "456" else "789"
  //error:  illegal start of simple expression
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
override def toString = "123:" + (if (true) "456" else "789")
```

Comment: It was useful to me when I realized that "simple expression" is in contrast to "expr": https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L134  It clarifies similar questions like why can't I `(Console println throw new RuntimeException)`.

Comment: Yeah, there a few precedence issues regarding these expressions. Check this out http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/uncluttering-control.html, maybe in the near future...

Answer (score 0):

[pedrofurla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480674/pedrofurla) is right. With your expression the compiler tries to mix the string with the if and fails. Using parenthesis you eliminate ambiguity in your expressions.

```
class MyClass{
   override def toString = "123:" + (if (true) "456" else "789")
}
```

I found this simple online service where you can test your scala expressions: http://www.simplyscala.com/